# How to solve $\frac{dy}{dt} = ky^{1+c}$ with $c, k \in \Bbb R_0^+$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was preparing for a math test and I found an exercise where I needed to find the solution y(t) of the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} = ky^{1+c} $$ if $y(0) = y_0 $ . Once this was found, I also needed to prove that there was a finite point of time t=T such that $\lim_{t<\to T} = +\infty$, but I couldn't find anything that is worth to mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a separable equation, so you just have to integrate
$$
y^{-c-1}y'=k.
$$